# Local repository in Informatica 9.1

Tags: repository, informatica, informatica-powercenter

Can anyone tell me how to create a local repository in Informatica 9.1?
is it possible to use a local folder as repository?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to backup the informatica objects, you can export them in xml format and save them in your local folder. However you cannot directly develop mappings using a local folder, you need to setup a repository server.

Comment: Then how about setting up the server in the same machine?

Comment: Of course you can, then you will have to install informatica server in your local machine. Once installed you will be able to configure domain and repository services.